# Is Test Set Preprocessing really needed in mlr3?

Tags: mlr3

When I include preprocessing (selection, imputation, transformation etc) steps in the modeling framework, do I need to repeat this for the test set before prediction when using the mlr3 framework. I don't think so but I want to make sure about this.

Below is a simple example about feature selection in the task. Do I really need to include the same feature in the test set or this is not needed (test2 line)? Results are identical

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'tune':
#>   method                   from   
#>   required_pkgs.model_spec parsnip
library(survival)
library(mlr3verse)
#> Loading required package: mlr3
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'mlr3verse'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:tune':
#> 
#>     tune
library(mlr3proba)


data = as_tibble(actg) 

set.seed(123)
split <- data  %>% initial_split(prop = 0.8, strata = censor_d)    
train <- split %>% training()
test  <- split %>% testing()

Task = TaskSurv$new(id = "ACTG", backend = train,  time = "time_d", event = "censor_d") 
Task$add_strata("censor_d")
Task$select(cols = c("txgrp","sex", "raceth", "ivdrug", "cd4", "age"))

rsf = lrn("surv.rfsrc", na.action = "na.impute") 
rsf$train(Task)

test2 = test %>% select(time_d, censor_d, txgrp, sex, raceth, ivdrug, cd4, age) # Is this step required for mlr3?

rsf$predict_newdata(test)$score()
#> surv.cindex 
#>    0.647943
rsf$predict_newdata(test2)$score()
#> surv.cindex 
#>    0.647943
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: No matter what kind of ml pipeline you use it should be automatically applied to the test data. If you find a case in which this is not so, it is most likely a bug.

Comment: @missuse. This is my understanding. Is this true even with $predict_newdata in which external data not linked to the task is used. Specifically, I want to ensure the extra variables in test set are not used in predicting and only the variables used in training are used in prediction.

Comment: models trained on a set of variables can not use other variables practically no matter what type of model/package you use.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case you don't need to remove features from the test set, as any model that was learned on the training set with the selected features will only use those (other features are simply ignored).

In general, it depends on what you want to do. For example, do you need to impute missing values on the test set if you've done that on the training set? Yes, because your model will not know what to do with missing features. If you normalize features for training, do you need to do it for testing? Yes, because otherwise you'll be giving your model feature values that may be far outside of any range it has seen before.

In both cases, you need to apply the same imputing or normalization that you used for the training data on the test data. One easy way to do this is to use [mlr3pipelines](https://mlr3pipelines.mlr-org.com).