# Follow Up Question About Whether Preprocessing Test Set Is Needed

Tags: mlr3

Please refer to the previous question here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/71389007/17537724)

With the pipeline below, will imputation, scaling and dummying variables be performed automatically on test set when predicting?

```
rsf = as_learner(po("imputemedian")  %>>%
                 po("imputemode")    %>>% 
                 po("scale")         %>>%
                 po("encode")        %>>% 
                 lrn("surv.rfsrc")
```

Another question, if I create a learner with specific hyperparameters for example based on a published model and I want to use it for prediction only without training. What would happen if I use two different data sets? Do I need to de-select non-influential variables from the data set? I assume so since all variables will be used in this case since model is not trained

```
rsf = as_learner(po("imputemedian")  %>>%
                 po("imputemode")    %>>% 
                 po("scale")         %>>%
                 po("encode")        %>>% 
                 lrn("surv.rfsrc",
                     ntree    = 1200,
                     mtry     = 2,
                     nodesize = 10,
                     nsplit   = 1)
```

Comment: Keep each question separate - that way it's easier to have an accepted answer (multiple questions might be answered separately by different people and then you won't be able to mark one (and only one) as the correct answer

Comment: You might also want to post generic ML understanding questions to https://stats.stackexchange.com/ rather than stackoverflow or search there for possible answers.

Comment: How would you use a learner without training by just defining the hyperparamters? Do you mean without tuning?